# How to compute the range of the map from Google Map API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the satellite map by using Google Map API in certain region, like minlon=-120, maxlon=-115, minlat=30, maxlat=35. However, the API's parameters used for setting the map range are: center=lat,lon, zoom=zoomlevel, size=xpixels X ypixels, not for setting the lat&lon range of the map. Is there a way to specify the range of the map using the lat&lon? Or what's the relation between the map range to the zoomlevel & size parameters for a given center point?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [google.maps.Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) fitBounds method.